# curl (3) and "URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"

Tags: url, curl

I have been trying to figure out why i cant run this piece of code for a while now.

```
curl -X POST '<a href="http://tp-api.herokuapp.com/beacons/" rel="nofollow">tp-api-server.herokuapp.com/beacons</a>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"beacons": [{"id": "a", "location": [10, 0]}, {"id": "b", "location": [0, 10]}, {"id": "c", "location": [0, 0]} ]}'
```

Output:

> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

All help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can't just put an HTML anchor link in the command.  Remove this and put the URL at the end of the command:

```
curl -X POST
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-d '{"beacons": [{"id": "a", "location": [10, 0]}, {"id": "b", "location": [0, 10]}, {"id": "c", "location": [0, 0]} ]}'
http://tp-api.herokuapp.com/beacons/
```

One liner:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"beacons": [{"id": "a", "location": [10, 0]}, {"id": "b", "location": [0, 10]}, {"id": "c", "location": [0, 0]} ]}' http://tp-api.herokuapp.com/beacons/
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
curl -X POST 'http://tp-api.herokuapp.com/beacons/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"beacons": [{"id": "a", "location": [10, 0]}, {"id": "b", "location": [0, 10]}, {"id": "c", "location": [0, 0]} ]}'
```

the 'a' tag doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I checked the URL 'tp-api-server.herokuapp.com/beacons' , and it doesn't have any key as "id" which you have mentioned in your post request.

Try this , {"beacons": {"a": [10,  0], "b": [ 0, 10], "c": [ 0,  0] }}